# How to vary WooCommerce product prices based on order dates

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

I want to build a WooCommerce website where the prices of products change automatically based on the date that the product is ordered (e.g. during seasonal periods, weekends/weekdays, etc.)

Can this be done with a plugin, or will code need to be written?

Answer (score 0):

I've found 6 Wordpress plugins that provide the functionality to vary prices of bookings/rentals according to dates and date ranges. All are premium. In no particular order they are:

1. [RnB - WooCommerce Booking & Rental Plugin](https://codecanyon.net/item/rnb-woocommerce-rental-booking-system/14835145)
2. [WooCommerce Easy Booking](https://wordpress.org/plugins/woocommerce-easy-booking-system/) (requires the extension "[Easy Booking: Pricing](https://easy-booking.me/addon/pricing/)")
3. [YITH Booking and Appointment for WooCommerce](https://yithemes.com/themes/plugins/yith-woocommerce-booking/)
4. [WooCommerce Bookings And Appointments](https://www.pluginhive.com/product/woocommerce-booking-and-appointments/)
5. [WooCommerce Bookings](https://woocommerce.com/products/woocommerce-bookings/) (requires the extension "[WooCommerce Bookings Availability](https://woocommerce.com/products/bookings-availability/)"
6. [Booking & Appointment Plugin for WooCommerce](https://www.tychesoftwares.com/store/premium-plugins/woocommerce-booking-plugin/)

Hopefully somebody finds this information useful.